# Java Slot Machine Slot Comparison Trouble

Tags: java

I've been working on a slot machine program for class and have been having trouble figuring out how to compare the different "slots" on the machine to determine whether or not there are matches and tell the program how to proceed with calculate winnings. I originally thought of storing each result of my random number generator in a variable and then comparing them but am unsure of how to do this. I am unable to use arrays or lists or anything like that unfortunately. Thanks in advance and sorry if my code looks sloppy.

```
import java.util.*;

//Start Program
public class Slots
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   //Start Main

    //=====Declare Variables=====
    int pool            = 0,
        won             = 0,
        slot_disp       = 0,
        slot0           = 0,
        slot1           = 0,
        slot2           = 0,
        slot3           = 0,
        slot4           = 0,
        matches         = 0,
        bet             = 0;

    boolean again       = true;

    String  msg         = "",
            ans         = "";

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    //=====Welcome and Start=====
    System.out.println("\t* * * Welcome to SLOTS * * *");

    System.out.print("\nEnter amount of money to play: ");
    pool = key.nextInt();

    while(again)
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter your bet: ");
        bet = key.nextInt();

        while(bet < 0 || bet > pool)//-----Bet Validation-----
        {
            System.out.println("\tInvalid bet of : " + (double)bet);
            System.out.println("\tFunds available: " + (double)pool);
            System.out.print("\tRe-Enter bet     : ");
            bet = key.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int cntSlot = 0; cntSlot < 5; cntSlot++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            slot_disp = rand.nextInt(5);
            //=====Converting Random Number into Slot Display=====
            switch(slot)
            {
                case 0:

                    msg = "Cherries";
                    break;

                case 1:

                    msg = "Oranges";
                    break;

                case 2:

                    msg = "Plums";
                    break;

                case 3:

                    msg = "Melons";
                    break;

                case 4:

                    msg = "Bars";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print(msg + "   ");
        }//-----End Slot Conversion Loop-----

        //=====Comparing Slot Output to Determine Winnings=====


        switch(matches)
        {
            case 2:

                won = 0;
                break;

            case 3:

                won = bet * 2;
                break;

            case 4:

                won = bet * 3;
                break;

            case 5:

                won = bet * 4;
                break;

            default:

                won = 0;
        }

        (double)(pool = (pool - bet) + won);

        //=====Displaying the Results=====

        if(matches == 5)//-----Jackpot-----
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n * * * You hit the JACKPOT * * *");
            System.out.println("You Won: " + won);
        }

        if(matches > 2 && match < 5)//-----Winner-----
            System.out.println("\n\nYou WIN: " + won);
        else
            System.out.println("\n\n\nNo matches, sorry you lost.");

        if(pool <= 0)//-----Game Over-----
        {
            System.out.println("\n> > > You ran out of money. < < < ");
            System.out.println("\nRestart the game to play again");
            again = false;
            break;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("\nAvailable money: " + (double)pool);


        //=====Asking User if they want to Continue=====
        if(pool > 0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to play again (y/n): ");
            ans = key.next();
        }

        if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            again = true;
        else
            again = false;
    }

    System.out.println("Game over, cash out: " + (double)pool);
    System.out.println("\nThanks for playing the Slots!");

}   //End Main
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use an `int[] hits = new int[5];` array to store for each value how often it was selected. in the loop increment `hits(slot) += 1;`. Later, loop over the array to find the maximum.